# Creating a Laravel based CRM that integrates with Gmail

Tags: php, mysql, email, laravel

Interested in creating a web-based CRM application that can do metrics based on emails. I'm using Laravel (PHP) for the creation of this application and the client is using Google Business Apps (Gmail). Gmail provides an API that allows you to take different actions. My main interest is running metrics and viewing stats on the customer emails (e.g. response times, most active customer, least active customer, etc).

The other approach is to somehow download all the emails to a MySQL database and query them directly.

Can someone suggest a method to query my Gmail email from Laravel that involves these methods or even a different method?

Answer (score 2):

Why not try using IMAP? This way it won't be Gmail specific and you could use almost any email provider. From there you could parse out all the info you need from the email headers (sender, date, subject, etc) and store it in a DB. PHP has a module for IMAP but there are also some nice composer packages such as [Fetch](https://github.com/tedious/Fetch) that will help speed up development.